# How to use "where not" in a Laravel Model Relationship?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, model, laravel-5

I have a user table similar to:

```
=== users ===
id: int (PK)
name: string
is_coach: bool
...
```

and a coach request table similar to:

```
=== coach_requests ===
id: int (PK)
student_id: int(FK => users.id)
coach_id: int(FK => users.id)
...
```

I also have the corresponding Laravel models (i.e. `User` and `CoachRequest`).

In the `User` model, I wish to make a method such that given a specified user, return all users with `is_coach = true`, except:

- him/herself and
- users who have already been matched with that person as a coach in the `coach_requests` table.

For example consider the following sample data:

**users**

```
(1, "A", false)
(2, "B", true)
(3, "C", true)
(4, "D", true)
(5, "E", true)
(6, "F", true)
```

**coach_requests**

```
(1, 2, 3)
(2, 2, 4)
(3, 3, 2)
(4, 3, 6)
(5, 4, 5)
(6, 4, 6)
(7, 5, 6)
(8, 6, 5)
(9, 1, 4)
```

Now if I was user with:

- id 1 (i.e. User "A"), return user ids: 2, 3, 5 and 6
- id 2, return user ids: 5, 6
- id 3, return user ids: 4, 5
- id 4, return user ids: 2, 3
- id 5, return user ids: 2, 3, 4
- id 6, return user ids: 2, 3, 4

How can I do this using Laravel?

So far all I have is this:

```
public function scopeOfFreeCoaches($query) {
    return $query->where([
        'is_coach' => true,
    ]);
}
```

So not much!

Many Thanks!

Comment: This is a case where a raw query might be the easiest way to go since it's kind of custom:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/database

Comment: I'm not even sure what the raw one for this would be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @purpleninja raw query, I managed to figure out how to do this using Laravel:

```
public function getPotentialCoaches()
{
    return
        User::where('is_coach', true)
        ->where('id', '<>', $this->id)
        ->whereNotIn('id', function ($query) {
            $query->select('coach_id')
                ->from('coach_requests')
                ->where('student_id', $this->id);
        })
        ->get();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a raw query on the top of my head:

```
SELECT u.id FROM users AS u
WHERE u.is_coach = true
AND u.id <> ’$userId’
AND u.id NOT IN(
    SELECT student_id FROM coach_requests
    WHERE coach_id = ’$userId’
)
```

Quickly done and not tested so you may have to change it a little.